# Beat way to merge a external web to meteor app

Tags: meteor

I'm importing a external web template I found in bootstrap to build a intro page. It has it's own js, css , html files.
However I found it is troublesome to transfer the beautiful external web to meteor format by hand. How you deal it smartly?

Now I only can figure out that replacing the html() when the intro is created. (although I still don't know how to do it exactly )

```
Template.intro.onCreated(function(){
   $('html').html('the external code');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and dirty way is to put all js, css, and html into public\ directory of your meteor app since this directoy is served "as is"

After that you can start converting your js files (taking into account local and global namespaces) and convert html files into Handlebars templates. Converted files you should move to client folder. Css files you can put in client folder to allow its minification and remove references to css files from Handlebars templates of html pages.

Comment: Great that's what I need. Just putting all of them in public folder and the intro.html can be open by the url http://localhost:3000/intro.html Thank you

Answer (score 1):

/public folder is usually used for static files like images. I suggest putting everything in a client folder. Usually there will be a lot of redundant js files coming with the template (bootstrap, jquery, fontawesome, etc). Best thing to do is use http://atmospherejs.com/ packages for those libraries and you will most likely be left with the templatename.js file which deals with the html within that template which you'll have to "meteorise"